# Python - How do I submit a form with Mechanize

Tags: python, mechanize-python

I am trying to submit a form by using Mechanize in Python. The form is shown as

```
Form name: None
<GET http://www.wunderground.com/cgi-bin/findweather/getForecast application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  <HiddenControl(airportorwmo=query) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(historytype=DailyHistory) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(backurl=/history/index.html) (readonly)>
  <TextControl(code=)>
  <SelectControl(month=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, *11, 12])>
  <SelectControl(day=[1, 2, *3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31])>
  <SelectControl(year=[*2015, 2014, 2013, 2012, 2011, 2010, 2009, 2008, 2007, 2006, 2005, 2004, 2003, 2002, 2001, 2000, 1999, 1998, 1997, 1996, 1995, 1994, 1993, 1992, 1991, 1990, 1989, 1988, 1987, 1986, 1985, 1984, 1983, 1982, 1981, 1980, 1979, 1978, 1977, 1976, 1975, 1974, 1973, 1972, 1971, 1970, 1969, 1968, 1967, 1966, 1965, 1964, 1963, 1962, 1961, 1960, 1959, 1958, 1957, 1956, 1955, 1954, 1953, 1952, 1951, 1950, 1949, 1948, 1947, 1946, 1945])>
  <SubmitControl(<None>=Submit) (readonly)>>
```

We can see that there is a SubmitControl here. And then I am trying to fill out this form and submit. Code is shown as below.

```
br.form['code'] = "KJFK"
br.form['month'] = ["1",]
br.form['day'] = ["3",]
br.form['year'] = ["2014",]

br.sumbit()
```

Then I got the error

```
AttributeError: class HTMLForm has no attribute 'sumbit'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You spelled submit wrong, try `br.submit()`